# How work cmp argument on sort function in python

Tags: python

Can you explain this python code?
Here how does `L.sort(fun)`  work?

```
def fun(a, b):
    return cmp(a[1], b[1])

L= [[2, 1], [4, 5, 3]]
L.sort(fun)
print L
```

Comment: Isn't it self explanatory and all of the explanation can be found by searching the python's documentation. Even possibly even here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/809/incompatibilities-moving-from-python-2-to-python-3/6139/cmp-function-removed-in-python-3#t=201705091116364415354

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official documentation:

```
The sort() method takes optional arguments for controlling the comparisons.

cmp specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (list items) 
which should return a negative, zero or positive number depending on whether 
the first argument is considered smaller than, equal to, or larger than the
second argument: cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x.lower(), y.lower()). 
The default value is None.
```

So you are trying to control the comparison using your own function "fun". Which say compares the values present at 1st index of the lists inside list(nested lists).
if you try to test it separately you will get -1 as the a[1] is smaller than b[1]
clearly and hence the output is "[[2,1],[4,5,3]]" which is already sorted

```
a = [2,1]
b = [4,5,3]
cmp(a[1], b[1])
```

You can give it a try changing value at 1st index something like this and you will understand how it is working.

Something like this

```
def fun(a,b):
    return cmp(a[1], b[1])
L=[[2,6],[4,5,3]]
L.sort(fun)
print L
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: when I use L= [1,2,3,4] I got an error message, why?

Comment: @SelvakumarAnushan: yes because then it won't be nested list. In case of L = [1,2,3,4] a[1] and b[1] doesn't make sense